# How to print without a newline in Golang?

Tags: go

The code is

```
fmt.Println("Enter a number : ") // a new line is automatically printed here. How to cancel that ?
fmt.Scanln(&a)
```

The output is

```
Enter a number : 
45
```

I want the output as

```
Enter a number : 45
```

Comment: Don't use `Println`, use `Print`.

Comment: The "ln" in "Println" stands for... line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick look at the docs for the fmt package would have found [fmt.Print](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Print):

```golang
fmt.Print("Enter a number : ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use:

```golang
fmt.Print("Enter a number : ")
```